# How to resolve PSRemoting error with powershell 7.2.1?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have problem when trying to use Powershell when remoting seesion:

> $PSSessionConfigurationName = 'Powershell.7.'
>
> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MyHostname

When i try these command this error appears :

```
C:\Windows\system32\Powershell\7.2.1\pwrshplugin.dll is not loaded. (with some stuff)
```

But this file really exists, os win server 2012 r2

Help please

Comment: try importing it: `Add-Type -AssemblyName "C:\Windows\system32\Powershell\7.2.1\pwrshplugin.dll"`.

Comment: Is the target machine properly set up for remoting _for PowerShell 7_? Perhaps [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Troubleshooting) can help.

Comment: This error happen when i try to set up the target machine.

Comment: Add-Type: Bad IL format. The format of the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell\7\pwrshplugin.dll' is invalid.